# Convert transaction XDR to object?

Tags: java-sdk

Given a base64 & XDR encoded transaction, how can I convert this into a transaction object?  I already saw [this answer](https://stellar.stackexchange.com/questions/1576/get-transaction-object-from-xdr-base64-string), but couldn't find the `Transaction.fromEnvelopeXdr(...)` method.

Comment: Try referencing this answer. It contains code on how to invoke "fromEnvelopeXdr". https://stellar.stackexchange.com/a/1653/1063

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method `Transaction.fromEnvelopeXdr` ([seen here](https://github.com/stellar/java-stellar-sdk/blob/master/src/main/java/org/stellar/sdk/Transaction.java#L180-L192)) was only introduced in recent months. Check [the repository](https://jitpack.io/#stellar/java-stellar-sdk) to ensure that you are using the latest version of the SDK.

Answer (score 0):

```
const {Transaction} = require('stellar-base')

const parsedTx = new Transaction('tx_envelope_encoded_as_XDR')
console.log(parsedTx)
```

This method i used in JS SDK.